# How can I align these two elements

Tags: html, css

I have a text box and a button, which is described with the HTML/CSS below.

Currently these two elements are appearing with the button slightly lower than the text box. Can somebody please suggest how I can get these two aligned so their middles are on the same horizontal axis? Thanks

**update:** apparently the outside world can't see this site. I'll post some HTML describing the controls shortly

**update 2:** This is the code:

```
<div id="SearchForm">

    <form method="get" action="/search/Tabs">

        <div class="search-box ActionControl">
            <input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search">
            <a href="/search/Tabs">Search</a>
        </div>         

        <div id="ContentArea"></div>

    </form>
</div>

#SearchForm .search-box
{
    padding: 25px;
    height: 25px;

    background-color: #F6E9D8;
    border: 1px solid #E7DFD0;
}

#SearchForm .search-box input
{
    width: 425px;
}

#SearchForm .search-box a
{
    background:url("../../Content/images/100/button-M.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border:0 none;
    color:White;
    cursor:pointer;

    font-size:8pt;

    padding-left: 22px;
    padding-right:22px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I can't access your example page. Error message: "The Web server you are attempting to reach has a list of IP addresses that are not allowed to access the Web site, and the IP address of your browsing computer is on this list"

Comment: @piquadrat - thanks for pointing that out. I guess the SysAdmins have set up ip filtering on that box... it'd be handy if you guys could see it!

Comment: The problem is that I think you have some style information missing. I tried recreating this in a new HTML page but it won't work for me. It's a lot of work, I know, but maybe you could try to recreate the problem with jsfiddle or some similar tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick fix... it was only a pixel out to my eyes...

```
#SearchForm .search-box a
{
    ... (Your existing styles)
    position: relative;
    top: -0.1em;
}
```

Using vertical-align doesn't work for me, so this just shims it.

Comment: That won't align when font size is changed

Comment: Using em measurements solves this problem. Example updated and tested at many different text-zooms in Firefox.

Comment: In which browser didn't vertical-align work? Works in FF and should work in IE 8. In this case, the vertical alignment is probably non-critical so I'd suggest that's 'good enough'

Comment: Actually, vertical-align works for me, even in IE7. I'd suggest that's a better approach than trying to tweak the positioning - vertical-align is a bit more explicit and also more robust if other changes cause height of either element to change.

Comment: I'm using Firefox 3.5.30729, the button still glues to the bottom in comparison to the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
#search, .search-box a { vertical-align: middle; display: inline-block; }
```